# Incorrect authorization to IMAP from PHP

Tags: php, authorization, imap

I'm developing a website where the users can access their mailbox from my application. When I try to connect to IMAP with wrong credentials accidentally, the screen waits for a long time and the server resources are taken up 100% and even if we close the browser we have the same 100%. Who can explain me how this happens and how can I catch the case when the username and password are wrong. I'm using [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6256-PHP-Retrieve-messages-from-an-IMAP-server.html) class to connect to IMAP server, but even without it, when I'm using PHP's native `imap_open()` I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of attempt time out

I had the same issue